# Can I see with whom I last played?

Tags: xbox-one

I would like to see with whom I last did a multiplayer match. I'd like to do this to add people I like and with whom it worked out pretty well.
I played Ryse: Son of Rome in multiplayer arena and fought some rounds with the same guy. Unfortunately I don't know how to add him since I forgot his gamertag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not yet implemented, but will likely come in a future update.

See also this [Gamefaq thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691088-xbox-one/67908541), [IGN thread](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/xbox-one-show-players-i-recently-played-online-with.453546291/) and [Xbox Achievements thread](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?p=6113069).

There's also a website dedicated to missing features on the Xbox One that Microsoft allegedly "listens to" ([source](http://www.videogamer.com/news/microsoft_listening_to_xbox_one_user_complaints.html)): http://xboxfeedback.com/